# WCF collection serialization, IList or List? Does it matter?

Tags: wcf, serialization

Is there a preferable collections object when serializing over WCF?  I'm trying to decide between List or IList, and wondering if it makes a difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does not matter from serialization point of view. There is no **IList** or **List** on the wire. Both will result in the same XML.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx):

> All list collections of the same type are considered to have the same
>   data contract (unless they are customized using the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute attribute, as discussed later in this
>   topic).Thus, for example, the following data contracts are equivalent.

```
[DataContract(Name = "PurchaseOrder")]
public class PurchaseOrder1
{
    [DataMember]
    public string customerName;
    [DataMember]
    public Collection<Item> items;
    [DataMember]
    public string[] comments;
}

[DataContract(Name = "PurchaseOrder")]
public class PurchaseOrder2
{
    [DataMember]
    public string customerName;
    [DataMember]
    public List<Item> items;
    [DataMember]
    public BindingList<string> comments;
}
```